# ¿como puedo poner un temporizador en ensamblador x86?

Tags: ensamblador

Hola alguien que me ayude y me diga que interrupción puedo usar en ensamblador que haga lo mismo que hace la función sleep de c++, por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigué, y encontré una función de la interupcion `15h`, que hace esperar por una cantidad de microsegundos, que es para escoger, hasta la instrucción que viene.

La función es la `86h`, como un microsegundo es 1/1 000 000 de un segundo, es preciso más espacio para almacenar un segundo. Son necesarios registros `CX` y `DX`; la cantidad en microsegundos debe ser anotada de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Escribí un pequeño programa para probar la func `86h` -->

```
model small   ; pequeño
.stack 100    ; 100 bytes para stack
.data

a db 'a'

b db 'b'

c db 'c'

d db 'd'

e db 'e'

f db 'f'

g db 'g'

h db 'h'

i db 'i'

j db 'j'

k db 'k'

l db 'l'

dollar  db '$'  ;final de la cadena

.code
inicio:
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax   ;conectar el ds con el segmento de la cadena

lea si, a   ;direccion del inicio de la cadena de caracteres para imprimir en el si

loop_msg:   ;imprimir un caracter de la cadena, esperar un segundo, imprimir proximo , hasta llegar al dollar
cmp [si],'$'   ; caracter de dollar ?
je exit   ;salir si es
mov al,[si]   
mov ah,0eh   ;funcion del bios para imprimir un caracter
int 10h   ;interupcion bio
mov ah,86h  ;la func que hace esperar
mov cx,000Fh  ;en este caso un millon de micro segundos
mov dx,4240h
int 15h    
inc   si   ;incrementar la posicion y imprimir la letra que viene
jmp loop_msg  
exit:
mov ax,4c00h   
int 21h     ;volver al DOS
end inicio
```

Te agradezco por crear este artículo, al contrario yo no sabría como hacer el efecto animación gráfica en la pantalla y aprovechar el timer   <3   =D